# rails with ajax retrive data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am basic to rails and Ajax. I have rails query to retrieve data from three table using JOINS. I want to retrieve data by selecting the date option, result should same page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUTHC.png)

Following is the rails Query

```
@query = ItemType.select("name, item_id, sum(quantity) as Total_Quantity_Itemwise, sum(price_value) as Item_Total_Amount, price_value, order_items.created_at Date").joins('INNER JOIN items ON items.item_type = item_types.id', 'INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.item_id = items.id').group("item_id").order(" order_items.created_at")
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: as per the query and image above i mentioned  so i need code in ajax with rails by selecting the date and click the button the should be executed